# Proving a subset is open in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I want to show that the set
$$S=\{(a+b,\dfrac{1}{b})\;|\; a\in \mathbb R , b\in \mathbb R^*\}$$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

To do this I write $x=a+b$ and $y=\dfrac{1}{b}$ so $y=\dfrac{1}{x-a}$

Hence
$$S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \; |  \; y=\dfrac{1}{x-a}\; \text{for some }\;a\in\mathbb R\}$$
So $\displaystyle S=\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb R} S_a$
where
$$S_a=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \;|\; y=\dfrac{1}{x-a}\}$$

and then argue that each $S_a$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.
Is this the way we do it or there is a simpler way?

Comment: I would simplify the set. This is just $\{(x,y) : x\in \Bbb{R}, y \in \Bbb{R}^*\} = \Bbb{R} \setminus (\Bbb{R} \times \{0\})$.

Comment: Sorry, should be $\Bbb{R}^{\color{red}{2}} \setminus (\Bbb{R} \times \{0\})$, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S_a$ is the graph of the function $f_a : \mathbb R \setminus \{a\} \to \mathbb R, f_a(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}$, which is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Thus this approach does not help you. But if you look at the set $S$, you will find that
$$S = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^* \tag{1}$$
which is clearly open in $\mathbb R^2$. The inclusion $S \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^*$ is trivial. So let $(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^*$. With $b = \frac{1}{y}$ and $a = x - b$ we get $(x,y) = (a + b, \frac 1 b)$.